# Alterar máscara de real Angular 2

Tags: angular, maskmoney

Tenho um campo com valor formatado com currency 'BRL':true:'2.0-0'. O valor que ele me traz está dessa forma: R$ 500,000,000. Eu gostaria de saber como faço pra deixar da seguinte forma: 500.000.000.

Comment: No angular eu uso a biblioteca angular-locale-pt-br ela converte todos os valores para o padrão brasileiro, basta declarar o currency normalmente 'valor | currency', o resto ela faz, também é possível alterar a formatação para como desejar segue o link https://github.com/renato/bower-angular-locale-pt-br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aconselho você utilizar um filtro de transformação para sua variável.

```
 angular.module("seuAPP").filter("nomedofiltro", function () { 
    return function (input) { 
        if (input.length <= 3) return input; 
        var output = input.substring(0,3)+ "."; 
        return output; 
    }; 
 });
```

com essa função acima você incluirá o primeiro ponto, basta completar os demais casos quando tiver 7 caracteres e assim sucessivamente.

na tela basta utilizar desta forma:

```
{{ suavariavel | nomedofiltro }}
```